# Три слові - чи правильно?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Чи правильними є словосполучення «три слові», «два відрі»?  Чи можна їх використовувати при написанні статей, у літературній діяльності та при офіційному мовленні?

Comment: Див. також: [«Чи вживається двоїна в сучасному мовленні?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/31).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> При числівниках два, три, чотири (навіть якщо вони входять до складених числівників) іменник має форму назив­ного відмінка, а при числівниках п'ять та більше — родового: три брати, чотири будинки, дев'яносто чотири проценти; п'ять братів, шістдесят будинків, дев'яносто дев'ять відсотків.
>
> У сполученнях із числівниками два, три, чотири іменник нерідко дістає такий самий наголос, як у родовому відмінку однини: матері (множина) — дві матері, сини — три сина, села — чотири села. Іноді особливий наголос іменники мають і в сполученні з числівниками п'ять та більше: книжок (родо­вий відмінок множини) — п'ять книжок, сторінок — шість сторінок, голок — десять голок, круків — сім круків, черепів — п'ять черепів.

[Зв'язок числівників з іменниками](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/zv_39_jazok_chislivnikiv_z_imennikami/6-1-0-111) на ukrainskamova.com

Отже, наведені вами приклади — поза нормами правопису.

Comment: Зазначу — поза нормами **сучасного** правопису. А от правописи до 1929 року включно таке дозволяли. Зокрема [правопис 1929 року](//r2u.org.ua/node/236) містив приклади «дві кни́зі, три вербі́, ха́ті, руці, три кві́тці, пі́сні, чоти́ри норі́ і т. ін.» і «дві відрі́, дві сло́ві, три я́блуці, чотири вікні́ і т. ін.» — хоча й відмічав їх не як основний варіант.